# Capture touch of iPhone navigation bar title?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uinavigationbar

Is there a mechanism to capture when a user touches on the navigation bar TITLE in a standard navigation based iPhone app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a subclass of UIResponder and can override whatever method you require

Comment: But what about navigation bar title only?